# count distinct items in stored procedure variable

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

In a Stored Procedure, I have value1, value2, value3, ..., value8

value outcomes will be between A and F.

After values are stored into variable, is there a way to see how many distinct values are stored in value1~8?

```
 example) 
 value1 = F; value2 = A; value3 = B; value4 = B;
 value5 = B; value6 = D; value7 = D; value8 = F;
```

Then after my count(distinct *), the result should be 4 different group.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select Value, COUNT(*) from (
select value1 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value2 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value3 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value4 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value5 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value6 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value7 as Value from sometable
union all 
select value8 as Value from sometable) as SomeTable
group by Value
```